# Python 3 is not reading my input right

Tags: python-3.x, input

I am trying to code a basic text adventure in python, just to practice since I haven't coded in a while. However, when I run my code, it skips to the very end of the actionRead() if-elif-else statement and prints the else statement. I can only assume that this is because it's not reading the input right. Any help? Here's the code below:

```
action = ""
room = 1

def commandLine():
    action = ""
    action = input("//> ")
    actionRead()

def actionRead():
    if action == "HELP":
        print("Type NORTH to go north, WEST to go west, and so on...")
        commandLine()
    elif action == "NORTH":
        if room == 1:
            room = 2
            look(2)
            commandLine()
        elif room == 4:
            room = 3
            look(3)
            commandLine()
        else:
            print("You can't go that way, stupid.")      
    elif action == "WEST":
        if room == 3:
            room = 2
            look(2)
            commandLine()
        elif room == 4:
            room = 1
            look(1)
            commandLine()
        else:
            print("You can't go that way, stupid.")
    elif action == "EAST":
        if room == 2:
            room = 3
            look(3)
            commandLine()
        elif room == 1:
            room = 4
            look(4)
            commandLine()
        else:
            ("You can't go that way, stupid.")
    elif action == "SOUTH":
        if room == 2:
            room = 1
            look(1)
            commandLine()
        elif room == 3:
            room = 4
            look(4)
            commandLine()
        else:
            ("You can't go that way, stupid.")
    else:
        print("That not a command, grue-for-brains...")
        commandLine()

def look(room):
    if room == 1:
        print("You are in a white room with bandages on the floor. You can go north or east.")
    elif room == 2:
        print("You are in a grey room with paintings on the ceiling. You can go east or south.")
    elif room == 3:
        print("You are in a pitch black room. You are likely to be eaten by a grue. You can go west or south.")
    elif room == 4:
        print("You are in a grey room with a large green splatter on the wall. You can go west or north.")
    else:
        print("An error has occurred. Please restart the game.")

# ACTIONS #

print("What would you like to do? Type HELP for help.")
look(1)
commandLine()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the results of `action` to the `actionRead()` function. Variables are local in scope, and a value that's assigned in one function cannot be read in another function without being explicitly passed.

You don't need to initialize `action = ""` in `commandLine()`, this isn't Java :)

Once you fix this, you'll run into another problem with passing the value of the room you're currently in, but I'll leave it up to you to fix, as it requires reworking your program quite a bit.

As a tip, if variables don't have the value you think they should, or in general your program isn't behaving properly, start throwing in `print()`s and see what you come up with - it'll often be quite useful.

Good luck!